# SameSite attribute in cookies

Tags: cookies, samesite

I have a website a.com that has third party app point to apps.b.com. When I login to a.com, I'm also authenticated to apps.b.com in the background using the same credentials. This is so the users do not have to login to access apps.b.com. I understand that browser sends all the cookies to apps.b.com when making the request to it. This is how it works now. Reading the article https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/ in regards to SameSite attribute, it appears apps.b.com is third party site. 
Now do I have to configure web server on a.com to set the cookie to SameSite=none;Secure OR do I have to set the SameSite=none;Secure on web server on apps.b.com?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you are making a cross-site request that needs cookies, then those cookies need to be marked `SameSite=None; Secure`.

So, for example if the user is on `a.com` and you have an `<iframe>` or `fetch()` to `apps.b.com` that expects cookies, then the `apps.b.com` cookies need `SameSite=None; Secure`.

Vice versa, if the user is on `apps.b.com` and you are making requests to `a.com` to check their auth status by relying on the `a.com` cookies, then those cookies need `SameSite=None; Secure`.

Essentially the pattern you're looking for is when the site in the browser location bar is different to the site that needs the cookies, then those are the cookies that need marking. So, depending on your set up, it may be one or both.